# Creating DOM attributes using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json using which I am creating elements on the fly with angularjs.

The json has a array of key value pairs that I would like to be rendered as attributes on the element. The array could consist of custom **data-** attributes or events such as **onclick**.

Lets say the json has the following structure:

```
var arr = [
    { key : "data-id" , value : "10" },
    { key : "onclick" , value : "javascript:window.document.location.href='www.google.com'" }
]
```

Could anyone please provide me a solution where I can render the objects from the above array as attributes of the element.

**NOTE** : The above array **arr** will be a propert of some other object.

Comment: are u attaching the arr to the $scope object

Comment: the arr is attached to another object which is attached to the scope object.

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: this is just hard to answer without all the relevant code.please share a fiddle and demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should write a simple directive for that, which would set element's attributes. For example:

```
app.directive('attributes', function($parse) {
    return {
        scope: { attributes: '=attributes' },
        link: function(scope, element) {

            var attributes = scope.attributes, 
                el = element[0];

            attributes.forEach(function(attr) {
                el.setAttribute(attr.key, attr.value);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<div attributes="elems">Some element</div>
```

and it will be rendered:

```
<div attributes="elems" class="ng-isolate-scope" data-id="10" onclick="javascript:window.document.location.href='www.google.com'">Some element</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0Yns3S4aYKWlgtpkHhMo?p=preview